# Backbone.js + Zepto.js examples

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, zepto

I am looking for an example set that utilizes Backbone.js + Zepto.js to build Mobile Web Application.

Answer (score 2):

You can get simple example in this link.
http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/03/02/how-to-build-fast-html5-mobile-apps-using-backbone-js-zepto-js-and-trigger-io/

Comment: Thanks. Based on my research Trigger.IO is fairly new kid on the block. Will need to do more research to evaluate this framework.