# Using Backbone.js with Zepto as an alternative to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, zepto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backbone.js + Zepto.js examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737826/backbone-js-zepto-js-examples)

How do I setup backbone.js to use Zepto instead of jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737826/backbone-js-zepto-js-examples

Comment: Thnx. Missed that question...